# Finding grok pattern for Log files

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I have a log file of the format :

```
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:28   0:00 [kthreadd]
```

I do not know how to read the timestamps that are separated by `:`.

The grok pattern I was able to implement till now is :

```
%{WORD:user}\s*%{NUMBER:pid}\s*%{BASE16FLOAT:cpu}\s*%{BASE16FLOAT:mem}\s*%{NUMBER:vsz}\s*%{NUMBER:rss} \?\s* %{WORD,:stat}\s*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below the grok pattern that matches your input log:

```
%{WORD:user}\s*%{BASE10NUM:pid}\s*%{BASE10NUM:cpu}\s*%{BASE10NUM:mem}\s*%{BASE10NUM:vsz}\s*%{BASE10NUM:rss} \?\s*%{WORD,:stat}\s*(?<time>([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])\s*(?<time2>([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])\s*\[%{DATA:username}\]
```

I have used the combination of **Grok + Oniguruma**

**Oniguruma**

The oniguruma syntax is the following:

```
(?<field_name>the pattern here)
```

- **field_name** is the key
- **the pattern here** is where you put in the regex pattern

**Grok + Oniguruma**

You can combine Grok and Oniguruma like the following:

```
%{SYNTAX:SEMANTIC} (?<field_name>the pattern here)
```

I have used [Grok Debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to validate the grok pattern. Also, find the output of the grok pattern below.
[image]